# sumTotal Duration for each request in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing an error while doing sum operation in sql

```
select RegisterId
, sub-RegisterId
, CreateDate
, DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00.000', RequestEndTime)), '00:00:00.000') as Endtime 
from CDHDetails 
group by RegisterId
```

Below are the listed data

```
RegisterId    sub-RegisterId    CreateDate               RequestEndTime
12325         95678             12-10-2018 09:37:16.000  12-10-2018 09:38:10.000
12325         917611            12-10-2018 09:38:10.000  12-10-2018 09:38:50.000
13567         91111             13-10-2018 09:40:17.000  13-10-2018 09:45:10.000
```

I want to group by Register id  with the sum of request end time

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? mysql <> sql server

Comment: That query isn't valid...

Comment: When you get an error sharing the error message is considered a bare minimum. I can see why you get an error because not all columns are part of the group by. And that DATEADD logic makes no sense to me as to what you are trying to accomplish. You have an aggregate as a row value or something.

Comment: I think I made a mistake in query.,can anyone guide me, based on the register Id, I want the sum of request end time

Comment: I am using sql server

Comment: What does the sum of time mean? Logically that makes no sense. Like adding Monday and Thursday.

Comment: I just want to sum up the request end time mm. Ss group by register Id

Comment: Again, what does that mean? You need to explain the requirement there because sum of time makes no sense. The time datatype is not a span of time. If you are using it for that you might want to reconsider. What happens when it exceeds 60 minutes and you are looking at the minute? I would also suggest you use the datepart name instead of the shortcut. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you use seconds?

```
select RegisterId,
       DATEADD(second, SUM(DATEDIFF(second, '00:00:00.000', RequestEndTime)), '00:00:00.000') as Endtime 
from CDHDetails 
group by RegisterId;
```

Milliseconds are really small and the total sum may be exceeding the value for an integer.

Note that I also fixed the `select` so it matches the `group by`.